# Angular nested Routes

Tags: angular, routes

I have some routes in my application I want to implement URL to access certain eaxam by it's id inside certain course for certain teacher like this:

> localhost:4200/teacher/100/courses/50/exams/150

how to implement it ? my routes goes like this :

```
{path:'student/:id',component:StudentComponent},
  {path:'teacher/:id',component:TeacherComponent},
  {path:'course/:id',component:ParentComponent},
  {path:'exam/:id',component:ParentComponent}
```

this works fine but when I reaches each route it removes the previous from the url for example :

> localhost:4200/course/100

then when I reach an exam inside that course the URL becomes

> localhost:4200/exam/50

**Edit:** like the answer I made it

```
:{
   path:'teacher/:id',
   component:TeacherComponent,
   children: [{
      path: 'courses/:id',
      component: SomeComponent,
      children: [{
         path: 'exams/:id',
         component: SomeOtherComponent
      }]
   }]
}
```

and in order to navigate

```
this.router.navigate(['courses/'+this.myCourses[i].courseCode],{relativeTo:this.activatedRoute})
```

this actually does change the URL but it doesn't change the view so it doesn't navigate to the course component!

Answer (score 0):

Use [child routes](https://angular.io/guide/router#nesting-routes). Example:

```
{
   path:'teacher/:id',
   component:TeacherComponent,
   children: [{
      path: 'courses/:id',
      component: SomeComponent,
      children: [{
         path: 'exams/:id',
         component: SomeOtherComponent
      }]
   }]
}
```

You can then navigate to a child route using the `navigate()` method as in your example, but note that `navigate()` uses paths relative to the route passed in the `relativeTo` param.

So based on your example, `this.router.navigate(['courses/'+this.myCourses[i].courseCode],{relativeTo:this.activatedRoute})` will only work if `this.activatedRoute` is /teacher/:id.

You should also add `<router-outlet>` to your templates in order to render the view associated with each child route.

As a general advice I strongly suggest you take your time and go through the Angular [tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#relative-navigation)

Comment: thank you for your help , but how do I navigate to it ? when I use  router.navigate(['courses/',100])  it throws me an error : can't match any routes - (Note: 100 is not static i use it just as example )

Comment: I have updated the question please check it if you can help,,,thank u in advance